# Formatting Subqueries to Correctly Grab Groups of Data

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have been tasked with creating a query that will notify our team when two production labels are scanned in too close of a period of time.

The tables and fields I am using for this are:

MASTER_LABEL - table is in order that labels are created. DISPO_DATE is populated once a label is scanned into the system.

```
ID     ITEMNO    DISPO_DATE    STANDARD_ID   QTY
-------------------------------------------------
1      ABC       (DATE TIME)    12345        4
2      ABC       (DATE TIME)    12345        4
3      ABC       (DATE TIME)    12345        4
4      EFG       (DATE TIME)    45678        20
5      EFG       (DATE TIME)    45678        20
6      HIJ       (DATE TIME)    91011        14
7      HIJ       (DATE TIME)    91011        14
8      ABC       (DATE TIME)    12345        4
9      ABC       (DATE TIME)    12345        4
```

STANDARD - Table is used to extract cycle time to calculate average time to fill a container. CYCLETM is in seconds.

```
ID         CYCLETM(seconds)
----------------------------------

12345      220
45678      105
91011      175
```

The basic code I have (I know will need modified greatly) is:

```
SELECT M.ITEMNO, M.DISPO_DATE, (M.QTY * S.CYCLETM) AS "FILL TIME"
FROM MASTER_LABEL M LEFT OUTER JOIN STANDARD S ON S.ID = M.STANDARD_ID
WHERE M.DISPO_DATE >= SYSDATE - .5
ORDER BY M.ITEMNO, M.DISPO_DATE
```

Ultimately, I am looking to find the difference in the two most recent DISPO_DATE times and compare them to the ("Fill Time" * .5) of a container. I would like to only pull the difference in DISPO_DATE times that are < ("Fill Time" * .5)

Is this possible with some sub queries and group by's?

I know there will be issues with the comparison of "Fill Time' being in seconds and the difference in DISPO_DATE being in DATE TIME format. What is best practice to combat that?

Any posts that you can direct me to or content that will help with this is greatly appreciated. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the difference of two dates to seconds by multiplying by 24*60*60.  This allows you to do the comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT M.ITEMNO, M.DISPO_DATE, (M.QTY * S.CYCLETM) AS FILL_TIME,
             LAG(M.DISPO_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY M.ITEMNO ORDER BY M.DISPO_DATE) as PREV_DISPO_DATE
      FROM MASTER_LABEL M LEFT OUTER JOIN
           STANDARD S
           ON S.ID = M.STANDARD_ID
      WHERE M.DISPO_DATE >= SYSDATE - 0.5
     ) MS
WHERE (DISPO_DATE - PREV_DISPO_DATE) * 24 * 60 * 60 > FILL_TIME * 0.5   
ORDER BY M.ITEMNO, M.DISPO_DATE
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the help with this. I have tried your above query and am getting error: ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function. Is this from the LAG function? I have tried using OVER (ORDER BY M.ITEMNO, M.DISPO_DATE, FILL_TIME/((M.QTY * S.CYCLETM)/ M.QTY, S.CYCLETM (with the last fields that are separated by / in different executions). Do you know what may be causing this?

Comment: Other than the misspelled *FILL_TIME* in `WHERE`, query works OK in Oracle 11G Express: https://rextester.com/SHC67458.